# I have account_id on all of the tables in the database that belong to an account. Could this be why our database is using a lot of memory?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, denormalization, database-indexes

The application makes heavy use of data. It is a Real Estate Lead Management System each lead could make our users thousands of dollars, and accidentally returning other people's leads would be a sure-fire way to lose our customers trust. We make heavy use of the entity pattern on the client.  This requires us to get collections of data and store them as collections on the client. My thinking when I was designing the database was that if I had the account id on each table, that would make getting all of the data easier without returning data from other account, with fewer or more performant queries. I realize that there are other ways to handle this, but we were on a very short deadline and had to build a full app with ~50 tables for a beta launch in 3 Months.  That being said, we also have many queries that heavily use joins and group by methods to prevent (n+1) trips to the database.  Is it simply that analyzing lots of data is something that requires a larger database? The big problem is that we only have 45 Active customers currently.  The app is fast and feels great, we are just pushing the limits of the memory of the database.  The current database has 8Gb of Ram.

This is the pattern that I did.  I know it's not normalized for the keys but everything I have read did not seem like it would cause this issue.  But I'm not a database specialist and would appreciate any advice.

```
Account Table:
id
first_name
...etc

Record Table:
id
account_id
address
...etc

Analysis Table:
id
account_id
record_id
expected_return_on_investment
...etc

Comps Table:
id
account_id
record_id
analysis_id
cost
...etc
```

Comment: Theoretically you don't need `account_id` when you have `record_id`, since you can get to the account through the `record` table. But if you don't actually need anything from `record`, that would be an unnecessary join, and it's easier to join directly with `account`.

Comment: That was what I was thinking, do you think that having indexes like this could be a memory problem?  Currently, we are using a server with 8Gb of Ram

Comment: It depends on how large the tables are. You say you only have 45 customers, that's not very many. But if you have enormous amounts of data for each customer, then it adds up.

Comment: There are many tradeoffs, and there's no simple way to answer this without benchmarking the actual applications.

Comment: What's actually the issue? I fail to find anything concrete in your question.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if the extra forieng_keys will cause memory usage on the database to be so high.  Or if I should be looking elsewhere for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for better understanding, I suggest you post your database with an Entity-Relation Diagram. Because it's hard to understand and there is almost no information it is impossible to know what you are exactly asking for. Nonetheless, I will try answering it (maybe I don't answer what you expected).

The `Account` table id should be the `account_id` on all other tables. When sorting the data to get (for example) all records from a client, you would search for all with `account_id`. Then, to differentiate between them, you can use the id. Also, you don't need to add `account_id` to Analysis and Comps; as well, you should not add `record_id` to Analysis. Last but not least, `record_id` is not needed in Comps. Why? Because since you have the id of the parent element, you can fetch other id's stored in there.

By the way, if you want to make it safer, I would hash the Account IDs and store them in another variable, which I would call `hashID`. Then, I would pass that hash to the other tables. In case someone unauthorized got that hash, they would not be able to fetch the id.  If you have access to the database, by comparing hashes you know which user you are referring to. However, if you don't, you can't get more info from that hash (if he had the id, yes).